# Beginner question on user input and if statements

Tags: c, objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main ()    {
    /*Start variables*/
    int choice;
    /*Menu*/
    printf("Welcome to the conversion program, please enter a number\n");
    printf("1. Temperature\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &choice) == 1) {
        printf("test message");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This ends up making the user input something first, then ignore it and print the test message even if the check was supposed to fail. What am I missing? (There are no errors or warnings)

Comment: Did you look at the man page for `scanf` and look at what value it returns?

Comment: @Mat I am dumb. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf()` doesn't return the user's input, it returns the count of inputs that were processed. If you want to test the user's input, you have to use the `choice` variable.

```
int main ()    {
    /*Start variables*/
    int choice;
    /*Menu*/
    printf("Welcome to the conversion program, please enter a number\n");
    printf("1. Temperature\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &choice) == 1) {
        if (choice == 1) {
            printf("The temperature is 50\n");
        } else {
            printf("Invalid choice\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("You didn't enter a number\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This still has the issue of not running unless something is typed, and then displays all the text at once.

Comment: What are you expecting instead?

Comment: I was attempting to make it look something like this:
Welcome to the conversion program, please enter a number
1. Temperature
>1
The temperature is 50F

Comment: Are you saying that you're not seeing the "Welcome" message until after you enter the number?

Comment: That sounds like an issue related to how you're running the program. If you run it from a console it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You're not testing what the user input is, you're testing whether the user input anything (which is to say, whether scanf received input and processed it correctly). Add a nested if to test on the value of choice after confirming that the user was able to input at all.